# How to enable form option select based on first selection

Tags: jquery

I have a form with Dropdown A that asks for COUNTRY and includes the following (and others):

```
<select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" onchange="setCountry();" required="" title="country">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Australia">Australia</option>
```

and then I have Dropdown B that lists the States of Australia, which I only want to be available if Australia is selected in Field A

```
<select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" required="" title="State">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
</select>
```

How do I go about setting this up?  I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to js functions etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers... Brett

Comment: Well, the way StackOverflow works is that you do some research, make an attempt to solve the problem and then when you hit a wall, show what you've done and ask a specific question. As it stands, your question _could_ be interpreted as "I'm too lazy to figure this out on my own, please give me the code".  I'm not saying that's what you meant, but the way the question is phrased it's one possible interpretation.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for taking the time to provide a critique of my question.  I had done some research on here and elsewhere and as I pointed out I really have no idea about jquery and a lot of the function script that I read about made no sense to me so I thought that I would have a crack at setting up the base HTML (as shown above) and then politely ask for some tips or pointers on how I might achieve what I was trying. It certainly isnt a case of "I'm too lazy...give me the code." But thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btee1mbx/)

```
$("#country").on("change", function() {
    $("#state").prop("disabled", $("#country").val() === "Australia"? false : true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Harshal... I will give that a try.  As I mentioned I dont have much experience with jquery but I can see how you have used the IDs from the two tables to set up the initial function and that state table is disabled when the country value equals Australia but the last bit with the positive negative is a bit confusing for to me... Could it have been written ?true: false? or is this the way such functions are phrased? I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: We could not use ?true:false. because if selected value is "Australia" then we don't want other select to be disabled.

Comment: also for understanding last part please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Darshal, as well as pointing me to a good resource on js.  Exactly the sort of help I was looking for.

Comment: My name is Harshal and not Darshal. ;-) .. and You're welcome!